# How is the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator deciding which iso files to accept as input? - and a workaround

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, iso, usb-creator

The current version of the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions of Ubuntu) is easy to use. And it is a cloning tool, which makes it reliable.

It seems dedicated to creating USB boot drives for Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu).

I have tested with various iso files outside the Ubuntu family:

- Respins based on Ubuntu are usually accepted as input
- A few respins based on Debian are also accepted as input
- Debian live iso files are *not* accepted (they do not appear in the box for input files after selecting them).
- Other main linux distros for example Fedora and OpenSUSE are *not* accepted.

This is rather confusing and I draw the conclusion, that there is some filter, that decides which iso files to accept.

- How is the Startup Disk Creator deciding which iso files to accept as input? What is it looking for in the iso file or in the file name?
- Edit: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Well, you could always download and look at the code ;^)

Comment: Kudos @ubfan1 :-) that's right, but it is the long hard way. I hoped that someone who knows can answer, but you made me look into the code. It is interpreted code, already available in my computer, and possible to read ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Startup Disk Creator checks for two files in the `iso` file

Kudos @ubfan1 :-)

I looked into the Python code. At first it looked overwhelming, but soon I found a function that looked promising:

In the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usbcreator/backends/udisks/backend.py` there is

```
def _is_casper_cd(self, filename):
    for search in ['/.disk/info', '/.disk/mini-info']:
        cmd = ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', filename, '-x', search]
        try:
            output = misc.popen(cmd, stderr=None)
            if output:
                return output
        except misc.USBCreatorProcessException:
            # TODO evand 2009-07-26: Error dialog.
            logging.error('Could not extract .disk/info.')
    return None
```

which indicates that the Startup Disk Creator is checking for the content of the files `/.disk/info` and  `/.disk/mini-info`.

These are present in Ubuntu, Debian and many but not all respins. The funny thing is that the difference between Debian 10.2 and Kali is a trailing line feed. I checked with Debian 8.8. It contains a newline and is accepted by the Startup Disk Creator.

```
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/CD/debian $ sudo mount -o loop debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso /mnt/lp1
mount: /mnt/lp1: VARNING: enhet skrivskyddad, monterad som endast läsbar.
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/CD/debian $ cat /mnt/lp1/.disk/info
Debian GNU/Linux 8 "Jessie" - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170506-14:26
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/CD/debian $ sudo mount -o loop debian-live-10.2.0-amd64-standard.iso /mnt/lp2
mount: /mnt/lp2: VARNING: enhet skrivskyddad, monterad som endast läsbar.
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/CD/debian $ cat /mnt/lp2/.disk/info
Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 10.2.0 standard 2019-11-16T10:15sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/CD/debian $
```

So it seems that I have found a bug. The Startup Disk Creator does not accept an iso file unless there is a trailing newline character in the file `/.disk/info` or  `/.disk/mini-info`.

**Edit 1:** I reported the bug

[Bug #1860411: The Startup Disk Creator is glitchy when I try to use non-Ubuntu iso files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1860411)

Please help raising the heat by marking that [This bug affects you](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1860411/+affectsmetoo).

### Edit 2: Workaround - 'any' `img` file is accepted as input

You can trick the Startup Disk Creator to clone non-Ubuntu iso files, because it is willing to clone 'any' image file with the extension `img`. So **make a symbolic link**, for example

```
$ ln -s debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.iso debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.img
$ ls -ltr
total 924676                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 lubuntu lubuntu 946864128 Aug 18 13:02 debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.iso
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lubuntu lubuntu        37 Oct 11 11:18 debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.img -> debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.iso
```

I tested this in 18.04.x LTS with `usb-creator-gtk` and in persistent live Lubuntu Impish Indri with `usb-creator-kde`, and it worked for me. The following screenshots are from Lubuntu Impish Indri,

[image]

[image]

[image]