# 22.04 Startup Disk Creator doesn't open any .iso

Tags: 22.04, iso, startup-disk-creator

The Startup Disk Creator under Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't let me open any iso files.
It lets you chose the file, but the file then doesn't show up in the GUI and you can't start the process. Any Ideas? I use dd now - but I think this should work for anyone who wants to use the GUI Startup Disk Creator.

I tried an Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation iso and the and the vboxGuest additions iso to test.

I managed to write the iso with woeUSB though - dd wouldn't do with the win10 either.

The device I want to burn on is automatically recognized - I just can't open any iso file.

Comment: I just tried this on my 22.04 instance by selecting `Other` in the source pane and selecting a downloaded 22.04 iso. Inserting a USB Disk immediately selected that device on the `Make Startup Disk` gui. I'm not sure if it works for a DVD though - you would need to use a different method such as `Brasero` Perhaps [edit] your question with the media you are trying to create...

Comment: What ISO are you trying to burn?  Startup Disk Creator is noted for having problems with ISOs other than the one for the running system.

Comment: I think the problem is that the Startup Disk Creator is dedicated for Ubuntu iso files. But you can make it clone other iso files by renaming them to img files. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204462/how-is-the-ubuntu-startup-disk-creator-deciding-which-iso-files-to-accept-as-inp/1204498#1204498)

Comment: Startup Disk Creator **only** works for Ubuntu ISOs.  For other ISOs, you might need WoeUSB-NG (Windows) and for Guest Additions ISO that's not supposed to be burned to anything, you're just supposed to mount it locally on a given VM.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasWard, that Windows iso files and vBoxGuest additions should not be cloned at all (and the current version of the Startup Disk Creator is a cloning tool). But what I meant in my previous comment, it can be used to clone non-Ubuntu Linux iso files by renaming them to img files. This applies to all Linux hybrid iso files, this method will create bootable USB drives.