# Startup disc creator not loading any iso

Tags: iso, startup-disk-creator

I have ubuntu 22.04 and startup diskcreator is not loading any iso file by default. Even while locating, it's not recognizing.

Comment: More details are needed. From your question "Even while locating, it's not recognizing." what does this mean?

Comment: What iso file are you trying to use? The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator works for Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours, but if you want to clone iso files of other distros, it refuses unless you rename it to an 'img' file for example: `mv file.iso file.img`; see details at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204462/how-is-the-ubuntu-startup-disk-creator-deciding-which-iso-files-to-accept-as-inp/1204498#1204498)