# How do we create a LIVE USB on LINUX? (using command line "dd")

Tags: live-usb

How do we create a LIVE USB on LINUX? (using command line "dd")

i'm reading on the internet you type...

1. Insert your USB drive into your computer and use ‘df’ or ‘lsblk’ from the command line to determine the device name your flash drive has been assigned, e.g. /dev/sdb, sdc, etc. in my case the USB drive shows up on /media/asher/gentoo
2. Make sure the drive is not mounted. If necessary, unmount it with:

   sudo umount /dev/<device_name>
3. Write the .iso image to the flash drive:

   sudo dd if=/path/to/distro.iso of=/dev/<device_name> bs=1M

this does seem to do something however it doesn't write the LIVE USB ISO to the USB DRIVE

THANKS FOR THE LIVE USB HELP!

Comment: I wrote an answer to this a long time ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/1333139/43926. I suggested using Gnome Disks instead.

Comment: "my case the USB drive shows up on /media/asher/gentoo" that's the mount point, you have to find the device that's mounted there

Comment: an even easier way to create a live USB in Linux is to [install and use Ventoy](https://itsfoss.com/use-ventoy/) where you literally just copy the `.iso` file on to the drive you created.

Comment: In Ubuntu Desktop there is already a tool that is easy to use, the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator alias `usb-creator-gtk` or `usb-creator-kde`. It can help you identify the target drive. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204462/how-is-the-ubuntu-startup-disk-creator-deciding-which-iso-files-to-accept-as-inp).

Comment: I should also add a general advice about `dd`: it is a powerful but also very dangerous tool, because there is no final checkpoint, where you can double-check, that you have identified the correct target device. There are many reports about people who have overwritten valuable data because they have selected the wrong device. `dd` does what you tell it to do without questions, so when you tell it to overwrite [the drive and/or partition that contains] the family pictures it will do so. If you are using Ubuntu Server, you can use [mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely to be that you have not correctly identified the target device.

The device name will start with `/dev`, so if you insert the USB drive and then type `df` in a terminal window, you should see something like:

`/dev/sdb1        59279292  28167900  28067760  20% /media/asher/gentoo`

So the command would look like:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/distro.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Note that the command above has `/dev/sdb` not `/dev/sdb1` - because you should probably not copy the .iso to a partition on the USB but use the entire drive instead.

Comment: i tried using lsblk and df and the path is still "sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk /media/asher/gentoo" or /dev/sdc let me try another time!

Comment: sudo dd bs=4M if=./livegui-amd64-20240303T170409Z.iso of=/dev/sdX status=progress && sync

Comment: okay... works!  i had to use a different /dev not /media